# how to make a Linear polar plot in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

i have written this code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi
import plotly.express as px


data = pd.DataFrame({'value': [0, 20, 30, 20, 0, 10, 15, 10],
                     'bearing': range(0, 360, 45),
                     'compass': ['N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW']})

fig = px.line_polar(data)


fig.show()
```

despite the fact that the program has no error when i run it, i don't see any plot in the output. what should i change to my code in order to show the polar line plot i want ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify additional arguments so that plotly knows which columns are your `radius` and `direction`.

Using your data, you could do the following:

```
fig = px.line_polar(data, r='value', theta='compass')
```

[image]

Comment: i added it to my code but nothing changed...

Comment: are you using the most updated version of `plotly`? and are you running this code in a `.py` file or in a `notebook`? i am able to produce this plot with the exact data you've provided in your question